# Cannot configure domain provider with my Azure Static Web App

Tags: azure, azure-static-web-app, azure-static-website-hosting, azure-static-web-app-routing, azure-static-website-routing

I am trying to setup a **Static Web App** in Azure.

Initially Azure created a URL **purple-moss-0e5ca5f10.3.azurestaticapps.net** which pointed to my static web app. If I entered in this URL into my browser then I would access my application. All well and good!

Next step is to purchase a domain, and point that to **purple-moss-0e5ca5f10.3.azurestaticapps.net** . Dead simple right?

I purchased the URL **oliver-watkins.art** from a company called TSOHOST. Then I created Custom Domain

[image]

Initially I need to generate a TXT string which I did in Azure, and then sent it to my provider. (I should have gone with CNAME, but oh well. TXT is effectively the same I assume).

So anyway, I “validated” and “added”. Once the provider validated the URL after a little while the status of my domain went to “validated”. So this I guess creates a “connection” between the domain provider and azure I assume.

So now I have two domains that look like this :

[image]

On the domain provider side of things I need to “point” the URL to purple-moss-0e5ca5f10.3.azurestaticapps.net . I’m guessing this is the second step that needs to be done.

I create a record that points to the “purple-moss-etc-etc” with type TXT and TTL 3600. (Don’t ask me why the number 3600, its just what the support staff told me to put in!)

[image]

*Now nothing works.*

If I go to the **purple-moss-etc-etc** URL I get nothing. If I go to **oliver-watkins.art** I get nothing.

I do not understand why such a simple procedure is so complicated! 10-15 years ago it took me like half an hour to get a website up and running.

How do I resolve this issue? THanks.